# Why does installing one npm package remove many others?

Tags: react-native, npm

I'm having difficulty installing a package using npm. The package installs successfully, however, it removes a whole bunch of other packages.

I'm not able to reproduce this on another machine. Here's the output of the package install:

```
[masterwok@crunchbox Caster]$  npm install react-native-google-cast --save
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
+ react-native-google-cast@1.3.0
added 1 package and removed 638 packages in 7.967s
[masterwok@crunchbox Caster]$
```

As you can see, it completely destroys my application dependencies. What could cause this? If I had to guess, I'd say some dependency is failing to be met which cascades down. I have no idea hah

Comment: I commented on the accepted answer regarding NPM5 issues.

Comment: can you post a small excerpt from some of the affected parts in your package-lock.json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why npm is doing what it's doing, but from the look of the output, package-lock, I surmise that you're using npm5.

Try downgrading to npm 4.

Comment: Wow, that was it. Thank you! Do you know why that would cause it to fail as it did?

Comment: I'm not sure of the specifics. It would be nice if someone more experienced with newer versions of npm would chime in. My understanding is this: npm5 creates a package-lock.json file when you install with --save. I'm not 100% on why or what it does, but on a quick google search it appeared possible that it could cause npm to rollback your installs. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: There are bugs noted with the latest version of NPM (5.0.3 as I write this). In addition to a few bugs there are also complications with upgrading to NPM5* and then running `npm install` on an existing project. Not a bug but a feature :-) is running NPM install from a machine with a pre-NPM5 version will not write changes to package-lock.json. References: [Missing dependencies after running `npm install` a second time](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16839) [npm@5 known issue tracking](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16991)

Comment: There you have it. Thanks!

Comment: [Missing dependencies after running `npm install` a second time](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16839) was fixed, and npm v5.1 was released; you can now try updating with `npm i -g npm`

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting this issue with npm v5.8.0.
I haven't found any way to avoid packages being removed when installing a new one, but have a relatively quick way to recover things.
In VS2017 Solution Explorer, right-click on the 'Dependencies/npm' node, and select 'Restore Packages'. This take a while to run through, and doesn't actually restore all packages, but gets most things back in shape.
When that's run through, right-click on the 'Dependencies/npm/aspnet-webpack' node, and select 'Update Package'. As this runs through, all of the missing packages are restored.
Hope this helps.